# Wrongly inferring variable type after it is assigned a value from within a callback

Tags: typescript

TypeScript is wrongly inferring the type of title inside the if condition

The infered type of the variable `title` that `trim` is being called on is `never`

```
let title: string | null = null;

const response = await fetch("https://example.com");

const newResponse = await new HTMLRewriter()
  .on("#title", {
    text({ text }) {
      title ??= "";
      title += text;
    },
  })
  .transform(response);

await newResponse.arrayBuffer();

if (title !== null) {
  title = title.trim();
}

export {};
```

Comment: That should not happen in TS. Which version are you on? For some reason it is not seeing that you are (potentially) modifying the variable.

Comment: @zoran404 The last version 5.3.3, and it happens in all the versions i tested this on

Comment: Well I checked this code myself and I did not get the error you are mentioning

Comment: Typescript should see that callback and know that the callback might be called and executed

Comment: @zoran404 see error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/DYUwLgBGCWagXBAzmATtAdgcwgHwhgK7DAQC8BxwA3AFC0AUAhkgJ4YDGEDAlOQHwQA3rQgQmAdyawIAM3AcAFgwDkisGAAOSeAHpdIAB5MAtptAA6DgHsTKnhbCKQGBrwHcYcEOQgqwICj2PHSiENCynrCgEACEZBREJHwiYmJeMRQZII7oJu76BNYQIKio1qh0YgC+tNU8vHRAA)

Comment: @zoran404 you probably have `strictNullChecks` tsconfig option disabled

Comment: @wonderflame You're right, I had it disabled. That is why I couldn't reproduce it

Comment: I bet someone already posted an issue on TypeScript's GitHub, but I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

Typescript can't follow your JS flow perfectly. The code analysis shows that `title` isn't changing for certain (only in `on` callback) thus, the compiler concludes that `title` didn't change, and knowing the value is `null` you are checking whether the title is not `null`, which is not possible for the compiler, and that's why in the `if` block the `title` is of type `never`.

Instead of using a variable you can wrap the logic into a function and make it accept a `title: string | null`, which I think won't be useful in your case.

A simpler way is to use *as assertion* instead of *type definition*. Due to assertion, the compiler won't know the exact value and this is what we are looking for:

```
let title = null as string | null;

(async () => {
  await fetch('https://example.com').then(() => (title = 'test'));

  if (title !== null) {
    title = title.trim() // no error;
  }
})();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/DYUwLgBGCWahBeCA7ArsYECGBnCOwAnaZAcwgB8V1gBuAKHoApcBPZAYwiYEpEA+CAG96EbAHcssCADNwHABZMA5ArBgADjgBcAel0gAHlgC2G0ADoOAexPKeFsApDImvAdxhwQiCMrAgBPY8DKIQ0DKesPAAhAhIaBh8ImJiXvBI6SCOxCbu+ijWECCEhNaEDGIAvvRVPLwMQA)

Comment: Why mix `await` and `.then`?

Comment: ignore the js code, I just wanted some callback to assign value, since I didn't have access to the `HTMLRewriter`.

Comment: Problem still happens even with a more predictable code like `await Promise.resolve().then(() => (title = 'test'));`

Comment: @zoran404 I don't see an error though. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/DYUwLgBGCWahBeCA7ArsYECGBnCOwAnaZAcwgB8V1gBuAKHoApcBPZAYwiYEpEA+CAG96EbAHcssCAAVCAewC20HCAB0hEDnnAAbiF5qwACxDImvAdxhwQiCAHIwWsA548GoiNABm12PAAhAhIaBh8ImJiNvBIMepE0Iq8tBAA9Gko8hAghAqEDGIAvvRFPCn0QA)

Comment: Pardon. Your solution works, I checked (I'm the one who gave it +1). I meant to say that the original problem still happens even if you used my simpler example with `Promise.resolve()` which looks like something I'd expect TS to recolonize

Answer (score 0):

It seems like TypeScript isn't recognizing that the title variable could be updated asynchronously before your trim operation. Here's how I'd restructure the code to give TypeScript a clearer picture of what's going on:

```js
let title: string | null = null;

const response = await fetch("https://example.com");

await new HTMLRewriter()
  .on("#title", {
    text({ text }) {
      // Directly check if 'title' is null and initialize or append accordingly.
      if (title === null) {
        title = text;
      } else {
        title += text;
      }
    },
  })
  .transform(response).arrayBuffer()

// TypeScript should now recognize that 'title' can be a string here.
if (title !== null) {
  title = title.trim();
}

export {};
```

I've explicitly checked if title is null and handled it directly within the text method. This way, TypeScript can better understand the possible changes to title over time, especially after asynchronous operations. By the time you reach the trimming part, it's clearer to the compiler that title has potentially been modified and can indeed be a string.

another approach would be to assert type

```
  title = (title as string).trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it happens because callback is asynchronous process, but you are checking title contents synchronously. Technically - if will run prior to callback being executed.

```
let title: string | null = null

const response = await fetch('https://example.com')

const newResponse = await new HTMLRewriter()
  .on('#title', () => {
    title ??= ''
    title += 't'
  })
  .transform(response)

await newResponse.arrayBuffer()

if (title !== undefined) {
  // Issue here
  title = title.trim()
}

setTimeout(() => {
  if (title !== null) {
    // setTimeout executes asynchronously, so TS assumes there may be other value at that point 
    title = title.trim()
  }
}, 1000);

export {}
```

I am not recommending to use setTimeout just to resolve the issue, but I guess it may be a good indication that you got a bug in your code, due to that `if` statement will always be executed before you will receive fetch response